# Portable soldering sponge?

Tags: soldering, tools

When I travel I take my projects with me. Gotta keep programming and connecting things.

[image]

I have a butane iron and it's great for travel, but is there a compact clean way to have a soldering sponge in my bag without risking getting shavings/drippings all over?

I may just put my golden wire scrubby sponge in a baggie, but I wonder if there is something more slick and reusable?

Comment: How about an [Altoids](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Altoid_and_tin.JPG/400px-Altoid_and_tin.JPG) tin? Even if you touch the edges with a soldering iron it won't melt. It's a bit bigger than a Beaglebone Black, if you need a template for trimming the sponge. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The most compact solution I've seen for this is sistema's [200ml rectangular KLIP IT containers](http://sistemaplastics.com/products/klip-it-rectangular/200ml-rectangular2). At 4.5"x3.5"x1.5" they push the boundary of "compact", but on the other hand they can take a decent-sized sponge. And the fact that they're water-sealed means that you can moisten the sponge where there's water and take it out onto a dry field without having to worry about the rest of your gear getting wet.

Comment: Eh? What makes that piece of tupperware special enough that it advertisement? Size?